# Is there any way of changing the password of an existing wallet?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, security

Let's assume that my wallet's password was compromised. Is there any way of changing the password or do i have to create a new wallet and transfer all the funds there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This answer depends on whether your .keys file was compromised as well. If an attacker knows your password and somehow has access to your .keys file he will be able to steal your funds. However, if he only knows your password and doesn't has access to your .keys file he won't be able to steal your funds. In the former scenario you should send your funds to a newly created wallet with a new password. In the the latter scenario you could restore your wallet with the 25 word mnemonic seed. It will then ask you for a new wallet name and you can choose a new password. Restoring is done as follows:

Linux and Mac OS X

`./monero-wallet-cli --restore-deterministic-wallet`

This should be done from the terminal from the directory of `monero-wallet-cli` itself.

Windows:

`monero-wallet-cli.exe --restore-deterministic-wallet`

This should be done from the command window from the directory of `monero-wallet-cli` itself.

Lastly, bear in mind that with the 25 word mnemonic seed is able to bypass any password set on the wallet. Thus, you should keep this somewhere safe.

Answer (score 3):

In that situation I would personally just move the funds to a new wallet. Because, if the attacker somehow also got hold of your OLD keys file, he could get access to your private keys.

If you really just want to change your wallet password, the only way I can think of is to do what dBRUYNE described above.

Answer (score 1):

**No**. There is currently no way to directly change you wallet password.

To change your password indirectly, you can write down your mnemonic seed, delete your old wallet files, and then run

Windows: `monero-wallet-cli.exe --restore-deterministic-wallet`

Linux/Mac OSX: `./monero-wallet-cli --restore-deterministic-wallet`

When the new wallet is restored, it will ask you to make a new password.